# Interpretation of Taylor's theorem

Tags: taylor-expansion

The following is Taylor's theorem given in a numerical analysis textbook:

[image]

I couldn't interpret what $C^n[a,b]$ means and what the intuition behind it is. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $C^n[a,b]$ is referring to a [differentiability class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes):

> In general, the classes $C^k$ can be defined recursively by declaring $C^0$ to be the set of all continuous functions and declaring $C^k$ for any positive integer $k$ to be the set of all differentiable functions whose derivative is in $C^{k−1}$.

Basically, $C^0$ denotes a class of functions that are continuous. Next, $C^1$ consists of functions that are differentiable with a continuous *first* derivative, and etc.

Essentially then, $C^n$ denotes the set of all $n$-differentiable functions, i.e. a function that differentiable $n$ times. The interval $[a,b]$ means that is differentiable $n$ times over the interval $[a, b]$ with the derivative being continuous. Thus, $f', f'', f''' \dots f^{(n)}$ exist on $[a,b]$ and are continuous.

The notation $f \in C^n[a,b]$ means that $f$ is in the set $C^n$ on $[a, b]$, thus has $n$ derivatives on the interval $[a, b]$. This is also basically explained by the next few words:

> Suppose $f \in C^n[a,b]$, **that $f^{(n+1)}$ exists on $[a,b]$** …

This implies that $f^{(n)}$ exists and is continuous because it at least must be because continuity is a requirement of differentiability. The fact $f^{(n+1)}$ is needed to exist is because it is needed for the remainder term of Taylor's Theorem.

Comment: Why is it $f^{\big (n+1\big)}$ and not $f^{\big (n\big)}$? Is it because the error term has $f^{\big (n+1\big)}$?

Comment: Also,why is it required to have a function with a continuous _n_ derivatives?

Comment: @Natasha I don't think I was very clear. $f\in C^n[a,b]$ implies $f', f'', f'''\dots f^{(n)}$ exist *and are continuous* on the interval $[a,b]$. The reason they must be continuous is because the $f^{(n+1)}$ needs to exist on $[a,b]$ (if wouldn't if $f^{(n)}$ were not continuous as continuity is a requirement for differentiability). The whole purpose for the $n+1$ derivative is because it is used in the error term and should exist for the sake of the error term as stated in Taylor's Theorem

Comment: When we say $f^n$ exist does that imply $f^n$  is not equal to zero?

Comment: @Natasha no. It's existence does not imply it is not zero

Comment: Could you please elaborate? For example, for a function f $\in$ $C^m$[a,b] has root multiplicity of m when $f^m(p)$ not equal to  0.